# Where to put criteria creation code

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, three-tier

Where should I put the code to create `CriteriaQuery`. Should it be in the data access layer or on the services layer.

Answer (score 1):

Data access layer. If for example, you want to change implementation from `jpa` and thus `CriteriaQuery` to something else, you don't want your service classes to be affected.